# Javascript popover loop not displaying

Tags: javascript, popover

I'm trying to make a loop, to display some link with popover javascript.
This is what i have

**accueil_hover.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#popoverOption').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
});
```

**accueil_blade.php**
(assuming the data passed as argument are OK)

```
 <div class="container">
      @for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($etablissements); $i ++)
            <a id="popoverOption" class="btn" data-content="here is some data" rel="popover" data-original-title="{{$etablissements[$i]->code_etablissement}}" data-placement="bottom" href="{{ URL::to('dashboard_etablissement/' . $etablissements[$i]->code_etablissement)}}">{{$etablissements[$i]->nom}}</a><br>
      @endfor

 </div>
```

But the popover won't show.
I guess this is because all my  links are having the same ID
But how can i make it different for javascript to understand ?
something like :
**popoverOption.$i** ?

Comment: Your problems is jQuery more then Laravel. You shouldn't use Laravel on your title

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything to do with Laravel. Also, it may be worth adding the tag 'bootstrap' if you're actually using the bootstrap library. Also, is `accueil_blade.php` a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Id` should be unique. You can use `Class` instead of `ID`

```
$('.popoverOption').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
```

Markup:

```
<a class="btn popoverOption" data-content="here is some data" rel="popover" data-original-title="{{$etablissements[$i]->code_etablissement}}" data-placement="bottom" href="{{ URL::to('dashboard_etablissement/' . $etablissements[$i]->code_etablissement)}}">{{$etablissements[$i]->nom}}</a><br>
```

Comment: Both of the answers are right... But using class instead of id in this case is more logical. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve unique `id` attributes like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  @for ($i = 0 ; $i
  < count($etablissements); $i ++) <a id="popoverOption_$i" class="btn" data-content="here is some data" rel="popover" data-original-title="{{$etablissements[$i]->code_etablissement}}" data-placement="bottom" href="{{ URL::to('dashboard_etablissement/' . $etablissements[$i]->code_etablissement)}}">{{$etablissements[$i]->nom}}</a>
    <br>@endfor

</div>
```

And the selector would be `[id^=popoverOption_]`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^=popoverOption_]').popover({
    trigger: "hover"
  });
});
```